# Use category path for product url in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

i want to use category path with my product url.

e.g
https://domain.com/product-url.html
to
https://domain.com/catA/sub-cat/sub-sub-cat/product-url.html

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its magento default setting in Admin Panel.

```
system > configuration > catalog > seo > canonical for categories/products->yes
```

Please clear **cache** and **reindexing** after that.

Comment: i do this but it will not fulfill the required result. i want to restrict the product url with full categories, even if it click from google or home page.